# JavaScript drop down panel for an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was making a webpage for a presentation. The page contains a login drop down panel, as given in the below code.
I might not have an internet connection during the presentation, and therefore the below code is inadequate for the presentation. Need advice on making an equivalent drop down panel for offline viewing as well.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#flip").click(function() {
                    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="flat_page">
        <div id="flip">
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </div><br><br>
        <div id="panel">Name:<input type="Text" name="username"><br>
            Password:<input type="Password" name="username"><br>
            <button name="Login">Login</button>
        </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my first question in Stack Overflow, I hope I didn't ask a question with ridiculously obvious answer.

Comment: Well first off, link to a local copy of jQuery, not the Google CDN version.

Comment: Ouch, please indent !!!

Comment: Could always download the JS script from googleapis.com and include it locally

Comment: aswell as a local version of jQuery, you could locally install and run mysql so that the database server is running on the machine the presentation is being used for. (assuming you are using mysql for the login), you'll need whatever server side language you use aswell - php, rails etc

Comment: Are you just trying to show a mockup with no server side behavior? I guess if that is the case it should be reopened as [MattD's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21937896/146513) seems to be cover everything in that case.

Answer (score 4):

[Download a copy of jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) and include it in the same directory as your page, then refer to it. Depending on any subfolders you may put the local copy of jQuery in will determine the `src` path you use. Having a local copy means you can still use your jQuery code without an Internet connection.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp).